# Update_or_create wont respect unique key

Tags: django

I'm using the following model in Django:

```
class sfs_upcs(models.Model):
  upc = models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=True)
  product_title = models.CharField(max_length=150,default="Not Available")
  is_buyable = models.NullBooleanField()
  price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2,default="0.00")
  image_url = models.URLField(default=None)
  breadcrumb = models.TextField(default=None)
  product_url = models.URLField(default=None)
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

And then I'm using the following code on my views.py:

```
def insert_record(upc_dict):
  upc = upc_dict['upc']
  product_title = upc_dict['product_title']
  is_buyable = upc_dict['is_buyable']
  price = upc_dict['price']
  image_url = upc_dict['image_url']
  breadcrumb = upc_dict['breadcrumb']
  product_url = upc_dict['product_url']
  obj, created = sfs_upcs.objects.update_or_create(
    defaults={'product_title':product_title,'is_buyable':is_buyable,
    'price':price,'image_url':image_url,'breadcrumb':breadcrumb,'product_url':product_url
    },
    upc = upc,
    product_title = product_title,
    is_buyable = is_buyable,
    price = price,
    image_url = image_url,
    breadcrumb = breadcrumb,
    product_url = product_url)

  print obj,created
```

I'm using the update_or_create method present in the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create and says that by passing into the 'defaults' dictionary the values that you want to UPDATE in case the object exists should make the trick... but I keep getting an "IntegrityError at ... column upc is not unique"...

Any ideas?

Comment: Give the ID parameter.

Comment: What do you mean? PrimaryKey? But, that should work alone, rigt?

Comment: With `update_or_create` you need a filter criteria, you give the update fields and the criteria values. The best filter criteria is the PK.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There are two parts to `update_or_create()`: the filter values to select an object, and the update values that are actually updated. The keywords filter the object to update, the defaults are the values that are updated. If there is no match for the filters, a new object is created.

Right now you're filtering on all of these values, since they're all provided as keyword arguments:

```
upc = upc,
product_title = product_title,
is_buyable = is_buyable,
price = price,
image_url = image_url,
breadcrumb = breadcrumb,
product_url = product_url
```

The `IntegrityError` means that, even though that specific value for `upc` exists, an object matching all of these filters does not exist. Django then tries to create the object instead, but the `upc` is not unique, so this causes an `IntegrityError`.

If you filter on just the `upc`, that field will never cause an `IntegrityError` to be raised: either an existing object is found and updated, or a new object is created, but the value for `upc` is unique.

So to fix this, simply do:

```
obj, created = sfs_upcs.objects.update_or_create(
    # filter on the unique value of `upc`
    upc=upc,
    # update these fields, or create a new object with these values
    defaults={
        'product_title': product_title, 'is_buyable': is_buyable,  'price': price, 
        'image_url': image_url, 'breadcrumb': breadcrumb, 'product_url': product_url,
    }
)
```

Comment: Mmm I didn't understand that from the docs. Was it me or is just not that clear?

Comment: @villancikos it is totally not clear! I also figured it out with this solution so thanks!

Comment: @Linucs Feel free to [open a ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/newticket) so the documentation can be made clearer.

Comment: Excellent, your explanation was better than the official documentation that doesn't let it clear.